# OpenID for Node.js cannot run the sample server

Tags: node.js, openid

When I try to run the sample nodejs server using openid found at
http://ox.no/software/node-openid

I get the following trace:

```
/home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:868

      return callback({ message: 'No providers found for the given identifier'
             ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:868:14

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:656:13

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:612:11

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:254:9

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:258:32)

    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)

    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:137:23)

    at CleartextStream.ondata (http.js:1150:24)

    at CleartextStream._push (tls.js:375:27)

    at SecurePair.cycle (tls.js:734:20)
```

Perhaps the problem is the openid_identifier I supply on the first page. I have tried

yahoo.com

www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

www.google.com/accounts/o9/ud

When I try www.google.com/accounts/o8/id I get a slightly different trace:

```
/home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:895

          return callback(null, authUrl);

                 ^

TypeError: undefined is not a function

    at successOrNext (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:895:18)

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:1008:3

    at successOrNext (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:909:9)

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:931:5

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:678:7

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:544:16

    at /home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:254:9

    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/node_modules/openid/openid.js:258:32)

    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:88:20)

    at HTTPParser.onMessageComplete (http.js:137:23)
```

Anyone have any idea what I've done wrong, how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1):

At least for me the following worked like a charm:

```
git clone git@github.com:havard/node-openid.git
cd node-openid/
sudo node sample.js
```

I then launched my browser to localhost and logged in with Google's address: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

It worked fine. So it looks like the sample on their website is a bit out of date while the one in their git repo works.